# Python Crawler Xpath to Get <br> Tag content

Tags: xml

I am a fresh who is study python crawler. I made a project which tried to get some information from a website. However, all the main content on those pages were under br tags, which was like this:

```
<div>
    <br>
        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
    <br>
        XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX 
</div>
```

I tried to use Xpath to get those Xs but the only thing I got is an empty list with no character output. What should I do to solve that?

Comment: Can you share the xpath you used? and also the sample html to which you are applying your xpath

Comment: In HTML, the <br> tag cannot contain content.  My guess is that your HTML DOM parser is treating <br> as <br/>, so the XXXXXX content entries are actually direct children of the <div> tag.  Try to get the parent <div> element using xpath, and iterating over all the children.  Does that work for you?

Comment: The code is as followed:    def getnovelcontent(url):
    chapter = requests.get(url).text
    res = etree.HTML(chapter)
    content = res.xpath('//div/div[@id="content"]/text()')
    print(content)   and the url is [link](https://www.piaotian.com/html/0/279/37759.html)

Comment: I tried to use the parent <div>, but it didn't work.